# Many-to-Many Select

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have 3 tables:

**users**:

```
id  name
1   Jack
2   Vasya
3   John
4   Robert
5   Dmitry
6   Dylan
```

**cities**:

```
id  city
1   London
2   Kyiv
3   New-York
4   Chicago
5   Moscow
6   Dubai
```

**users_cities**:

```
user_id city_id
1       1
3       1
5       6
2       3
4       5
6       6
```

I need to select users with Jack in London by Jack's id(users.id = 1) or users in Dubai with Dmitry(users.id = 5) using JOIN.
How could I do it?

What I have tried:

```
SELECT `u`.`username`, `uc`.`city_id` FROM `users` as `u`
    INNER JOIN `users_cities` as `uc` ON `u`.`id` = `uc`.`user_id`
    INNER JOIN `users_cities` as `uc1` ON `uc1`.`city_id` = `uc`.`city_id`
WHERE `u`.`id` = 1
```

It returns:

```
username    city_id
Jack        1
Jack        1
```

Comment: It seems you already have the correct terminology and know what you need to do, so have a go and see if you can do it yourself. If you're still struggling then post and edit to your question with the details of what you have tried.

Comment: Am I right when I think I should use JOIN twice on users_cities table?

Comment: Can't understand how I could use `uc`.`city_id` to select users ids from users_cities

Comment: Please clarify your question by showing your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You're so very close. You only need to `JOIN` to `user_cities` once for your query. Then use the `WHERE` clause to determine the users or cities you wish to filter on.

If you want the city name in the result set then make an additional join from `user_cities` to `cities`.

As you are joining twice on the same result set (`user_cities`) you are effectively querying that result twice, which is why you are getting duplicate 'Jacks'.

If this is not exactly what you need, then adjust your `WHERE` clause to determine how you would like to filter the result set.

```sql
SELECT 
  u.username, 
  c.city 
FROM 
  users as u
  INNER JOIN users_cities as uc ON u.id = uc.user_id
  INNER JOIN cities as c ON uc.city_id = c.id
WHERE 
  u.id = 1 -- Jack
  OR u.id = 5 -- Dimitry
```

Comment: In result I need to get Jack and John, because they have the same city_id in users_cities but I have only Jacks I'd which is 1

Comment: That is where the `WHERE` clause comes in. `WHERE user_cities.city_id = 1` -- returns all users which have city_id = 1. Have a play with that and adjust it to your needs.